# Using lambda as an argument : std::function or template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm studying c++11 especially interested in lambda.

After some practices, I assumed that lambda closure is an nameless function object.

So I wrote this code.

```
template <class callable_object>
void lambda_caller( callable_object lambda )
{
    std::cout<< sizeof(lambda) << endl;
    lambda();
}
```

I know that I can use `std::function` instead of using template, but I don't want the overhead while typecasting.

But I found one problem reading this question : [Why can't I create a vector of lambda in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477310/why-cant-i-create-a-vector-of-lambda-in-c11)

The answerer said, "Every lambda has a different type- even if they have the same signature.".

Compilers makes different codes for different classes.

So I think that my compiler will make another version of `lambda_caller` whenever I make another definition of lambda to pass.

Is there any way to avoid it, except using `std::function`? Isn't there any generic type for lambda closure?

Comment: Wasn't `std::function` designed specifically for this? You could write your own wrapper for a lambda, that offers the same object type to client code and allows you to call whatever different lambda is bound to it, transparently. If you wrote a good implementation, you'd end up with std::function (or similar).

Comment: @utnapistim: `std::function` is for *storing* callables. If you just want to take any callable, use a template - it also enables easier inlining. And if you want to store it, still use a template, and internally convert to `std::function`.

Comment: I didn't know about packaged_task. I use `std::function`s as input parameters, when I do not want (or need) to convert my class or functions to templates on the functor/lambda type (callbacks, event notification receivers, error handling policies, etc).

Comment: Unless an implementation decides to resort to deep magic, more often than not using `std::function` here will not save you anything (on top of being more troublesome and costly at runtime): a typical implementation will have a template constructor so different functor types will yield different instantiations of that constructor. In all likeliness there will also be *more* inner template machinery instantiations, too. The code you have right now is minimal -- there is very little you should change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't avoid it. Lambda is just a class with operator()() overloaded which executes your code. So different code - different classes.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` is the generic type for lambda closures. The problem is that each lambda may capture different variables. So it can't be reduced to say a function pointer and some data, because the lambda may have captured 3 variables or it may have captured 4. `std::function` will take care of making sure that enough memory is allocated for the data, but it comes at a cost(the data could be heap allocated).

However, if you are wanting to store several lambdas, and you know how many at compile-time. You could store them in an `std::tuple` instead. Which allows different types for each lambda. Unfortunately, C++ still doesn't provide a way to iterate over a tuple, but using [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html) you can.

Comment: C++ provides a way -- I am only 109 characters short of being able to post a [complete example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Hpv3w$25) in this comment.

Comment: @Yakk Thats pretty cool. Of course, I didn't mean it was impossible, just that the standard C++ library doesn't provide a way.

Comment: @PaulFultzII "`std::function` is the generic type for lambda closures."

I think this statement is either not true, or at least misleading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030880.