# I cannot pass lambda as std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Let's focus on this example:

```
template<typename T>
class C{
    public:
    void func(std::vector<T>& vec, std::function<T( const std::string)>& f){
        //Do Something
    }
};
```

And now, I am trying:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
auto lambda = [](const std::string& s) { return std::stoi(s); };
C<int> c;
c.func(vec, lambda);
```

It causes errors:

```
no matching function for call to ‘C<int>::func(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, main()::<lambda(const string&)>&)’
     ref.parse(vec, lambda);
```

Please explain me what is not ok and how to implement it with std::bind as well.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's because a lambda function is not a `std::function<...>`. The type of

```
auto lambda = [](const std::string& s) { return std::stoi(s); };
```

is not `std::function<int(const std::string&)>`, but something unspecified which can be assigned to a `std::function`. Now, when you call your method, the compiler complains that the types don't match, as conversion would mean to create a temporary which cannot bind to a non-const reference.

This is also not specific to lambda functions as the error happens when you pass a normal function. This won't work either:

```
int f(std::string const&) {return 0;}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    C<int> c;
    c.func(vec, f);
}
```

You can either assign the lambda to a `std::function`

```
std::function<int(const std::string&)> lambda = [](const std::string& s) { return std::stoi(s); };
```

,change your member-function to take the function by value or const-reference or make the function parameter a template type. This will be slightly more efficient in case you pass a lambda or normal function pointer, but I personally like the expressive `std::function` type in the signature.

```
template<typename T>
class C{
    public:
    void func(std::vector<T>& vec, std::function<T( const std::string)> f){
        //Do Something
    }

    // or
    void func(std::vector<T>& vec, std::function<T( const std::string)> const& f){
        //Do Something
    }

    // or
    template<typename F> func(std::vector<T>& vec, F f){
        //Do Something
    }
};
```

Answer (score 34):

It's because the argument (`std::function`) is a reference. It should be:

```
void func(std::vector<T>& vec, std::function<T(const std::string&)> f)
                                                                ^  ^
                                                                   |
                                                                   f not a reference
```

So that the argument can be converted to the parameter type.

Also, the type of the function should match. I.e. it should accept a string reference.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi No, [it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb02b67f42206b92).

Comment: @AntonSavin My original post didn't. I've edited since to be correct.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I've made f not a reference.

Comment: @bolov OH! You emphasizes the & on the std::string which is not a problem so I did not notice the other .. sorry +1