# Why Can't a Lambda be Assigned to a function Object with a Template Type?

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda, language-lawyer

There have been a couple questions related to *how* to work around this issue:

- [c++ functional, std::function with generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49732409/2642059)
- [I cannot pass lambda as std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030589/i-cannot-pass-lambda-as-stdfunction)

I'm not interested in work arounds, I'd just like an explanation of why this doesn't work.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T input, function<void(T)> func) { func(input); }
```

When I make a call like this: `foo(13, [](int input){ cout << input; })`
I'm assuming that the issue has to do with the fact that the lambda is not *of* type `function<void(int)>` but must be converted to that type. And I'm assuming that such a conversion is not permitted to successfully compile a template.
Could someone get me a reference that affirms this?

Comment: Template deduction rules say the types must be an exact match. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: For the template to deduce that, it would have to convert the lambda to a `std::function`. That's not how template deduction works.

Comment: this will work as you help to deduct the type.
template <typename T>
void foo(T input, std::function<void(T)> func) { func(input); }

foo<int>(13, [](int input) { std::cout << input; });