# 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Using Rcpp package to include C++ in R, I tried to compile my C++ file. Here is the error that came:

> 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

After investigation, I have been told that my code used some functionalities that are only available from C++ 11. So I need to add one line in my Makevars file. However, I found a vignette that says Makevars is not mandatory anymore :[Rcpp vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf). How can I fix this problem?

Here is the part of the C++ script that doesn't work:

```
std::function<void(const state_type, state_type, const double)> eqsir2(const Rcpp::NumericVector theta) {
  return [&theta](const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, const double t) {
    boost_array_to_nvec2(x, nvec);
    my_fun22(nvec,t,theta);
    nvec_to_boost_array2(nvec, dxdt);
  }
```

Comment: did you include `<functional>` ?

Comment: No. Where should I include that?

Comment: In your C++ file, where the rest of your C++ code is, that uses `std::function`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be able to use `std::function` in C++ you have to include the right header via

```
#include <functional>
```

somewhere in your code base.

As for the R side, you have to tell the compiler that you want to use C++11 features. If you just have a `.cpp` file that you include via `Rcpp::sourceCpp`, you have to add

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
```

to your `.cpp` file.

If you are writing a R package (the vignette you are citing is meant for that), then a `src/Makevars` file is no longer mandatory for using `Rcpp`, but using `CXX_STD` within `src/Makevars` is the suggested way for requesting C++11 when wrting a package. Alternatively you can use `SystemRequirements` in  `DESCRIPTION`. Citing from [Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code):

> In order to use C++11 code in a package, the package’s Makevars file
>   (or Makevars.win on Windows) should include the line
>
> CXX_STD = CXX11
>
> Compilation and linking will then be done with the C++11 compiler.
>
> Packages without a src/Makevars or src/Makefile file may specify that
>   they require C++11 for code in the src directory by including ‘C++11’
>   in the ‘SystemRequirements’ field of the DESCRIPTION file, e.g.
>
> SystemRequirements: C++11
>
> If a package does have a src/Makevars[.win] file then setting the make
>   variable ‘CXX_STD’ is preferred, as it allows R CMD SHLIB to work
>   correctly in the package’s src directory.

In addition, you have to make sure that the signature of the returned function and the lambda are identical (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030589/i-cannot-pass-lambda-as-stdfunction)). As it stands you are using references for only one of them. Both is possible, you just have to be consistent:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <functional>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <boost/array.hpp>
typedef boost::array<double, 3> state_type;

// references
std::function<void(const state_type&, state_type&, const double)> eqsir2(const Rcpp::NumericVector theta) {
  return [&theta](const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, const double t) {return;};
}

// no references
std::function<void(const state_type, state_type, const double)> eqsir(const Rcpp::NumericVector theta) {
  return [&theta](const state_type x, state_type dxdt, const double t) {return;};
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so where do I find the Makevars file? Should I create a new one? Where?

Comment: I'm not building a package, so what should I do? Only adding #include <functional> and // [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]] in my .cpp file?

Comment: I did but another error came : could not convert '<lambda closure object>eqsir2(Rcpp::NumericVector)::<lambda(const state_type&, state_type&, double)>{(* & theta)}' from 'eqsir2(Rcpp::NumericVector)::<lambda(const state_type&, state_type&, double)>' to 'std::function<void(boost::array<double, 130ull>, boost::array<double, 130ull>, double)>'.

Should I ask another question?

Comment: @AnthonyHauser Yes

Comment: I used your solution to solve my problem, thank you!