# C++: Passing a lambda as a function with template arguments makes deducing the template types fail

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Using a template type within the parameters of a function passed as argument (either as std::function or as a function pointer) makes the compiler unable to deduce the type when the function is passed as a lambda (see code below). Interestingly this works if the function is not a lambda.

Is there any way to achieve this? I've tried the following code with Visual Studio 2017 and GCC 7.4 and both fail, so it's unlikely to be a compiler bug and probably there is a reason for this behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void collide(void (*callback)(T)) // or std::function<void(T)> callback
{
    callback(42);
}

int main() {
    // doesn't compile: "could not deduce template arguments"
    collide([](int a) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot pass lambda as std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030589/i-cannot-pass-lambda-as-stdfunction) - same goes for function-pointers and lambdas. Though they can be sometimes converted to function pointers, the potential conversion cannot be used with template matching.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the same case, although my question is a bit more generic since it includes function pointers. What's suggested on that question (casting to std::function then passing) seems to work, although I wonder why the compiler can't do this for me.

Comment: "*it includes function pointers*" - hence my comment on the function pointers - lambdas are *not* function pointers. They *sometimes can be converted to function pointers*, but the rules are that conversions are not allowed when matching against a `template`. These are the rules. They do make sense and prevent you from accidentally breaking *a lot* of stuff elsewhere, but the drawback is that the compiler cannot, unfortunately, "*do this for you*" right here.

Comment: Didn't know that "conversions are not allowed when matching against a template". That explains it then, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following call

```
collide( *[](int a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
});
```

to convert the lambda to a pointer to a function explicitly.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f( void ( *fn )( T ) )
{
    fn( 42 );
}

void g( int x )
{
    std::cout << "g( " << x << " );\n";
}

int main()
{
    f( g );
    f( *[]( int x ) { std::cout << "main::lambda( " << x << ");\n"; } );
}
```

Its output is

```
g( 42 );
main::lambda( 42);
```

Comment: This results in `'operator *' is ambiguous` in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Although it does work in GCC 7.4. That's even more intriguing!

Comment: It seems to be ambiguous on VS because it could be converted to a pointer using different calling conventions. See explanation here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623

Comment: In any case, accepting your answer since it does work at least on GCC.