# Got an Error when using C++20 Polymorphism Lambda Function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to write a higher-order function via Lambda in C++, and got this code.

```cpp
void ProcessList::SortCol(std::string col, bool flag) {

    auto CmpGenerator = [&]<typename T>
        (std::function<T(const Process &itm)> func) {
        return (flag? [&](const Process &a, const Process &b) {
                            return func(a) < func(b);}
                    : [&](const Process &a, const Process &b) {
                            return func(a) > func(b);}
            );
        };

    std::function<bool(const Process &a, const Process &b)> cmp;

    if (col == "PID") {
        cmp = CmpGenerator([](const Process &itm) {
            return itm.GetPid();
        });
    }
    else if (col == "CPU") {
        cmp = CmpGenerator([](const Process &itm) {
            return itm.GetRatioCPU();
        });
    }
    else if (col == "COMMAND") {
        cmp = CmpGenerator([](const Process &itm) {
            return itm.GetCmd();
        });
    }
    std::sort(lst.begin(), lst.end(), cmp);
}
```

However when compiling, g++ reported that no match for call to

```
no match for call to ‘(ProcessList::SortCol(std::string, bool)::<lambda(std::function<T(const Process&)>)>) (ProcessList::SortCol(std::string, bool)::<lambda(const Process&)>)’
```

What's wrong here with the code?

Comment: Can't you just use `std::ranges::sort()`, with a projection to a pointer-to-member(-function), for this?

Comment: Fairly true, but I wonder why the code here doesn't work on earth

Comment: Aside: even if it could deduce T properly, `CmpGenerator` returns a lambda that has captured a dangling reference to `func`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem in this example is that a lambda is not a `std::function`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36030589/2069064).

`CmpGenerator` deduces its argument as `std::function<T(Process const&)>`, but a lambda will never match that, so deduction fails.

Furthermore, the body of `CmpGenerator` tries to return one of two different lambdas - which have different types. Those lambdas are not convertible to each other, so the conditional expression will fail. But we also can't deduce the return type of `CmpGenerator` since the two different lambdas have different types.

---

We can start by doing this completely by hand. `std::ranges::sort` takes a projection, which is very helpful in this regard:

```cpp
if (col == "PID") {
    if (increasing) { // <== 'flag' is not a great name
        std::ranges::sort(lst, std::less(), &Process::GetPid);
    } else {
        std::ranges::sort(lst, std::greater(), &Process::GetPid);
    }
} else if (col == "CPU") {
    // ...
}
```

This gives the structure that we need to abstract: we're not generating a comparison object, we're generating a call to `sort`.

That is:

```cpp
auto sort_by = [&](auto projection){ // <== NB: auto, not std::function
    if (increasing) {
        std::ranges::sort(lst, std::less(), projection);
    } else {
        std::ranges::sort(lst, std::greater(), projection);
    }
};

if (col == "PID") {
    sort_by(&Process::GetPid);
} else if (col == "CPU") {
    sort_by(&Process::GetRatioCPU);
} else if (col == "COMMAND") {
    sort_by(&Process::GetCmd);
}
```