# pass lambda as template argument (bad compile time) VS std::function (bad performance)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, std-function

I want to pass lambda function **with capture** to another normal function `f`.

I have found only two alternatives :-

### **1. pass lambda function directly, using template**

```
template<typename Lam> f(Lam lam,  something) {...}
```

**Disadvantage**: must be in header -> slower compile time

### **2. convert lambda to std::function**

```
f(std::function<void(SomePointer*)> lam, something){...}
```

**Disadvantage**: execution cost is more (+100% for my case, optimized)

I want to pass many lambda functions that share the same signature to `f` (good for 2).
`f` is a complex function with long code.  (also good for 2).

### Question

Is there any technique that have advantage from both solutions?

This link 
[Using lambda as an argument : std::function or template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999138/using-lambda-as-an-argument-stdfunction-or-template)  vaguely said the answer is no.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I will interpret that, by marking that this question is duplicated, you confirmed the answer is "no" .   :(

Comment: There is a middle-way, between `std::function` and a specialization each: Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11

Comment: @Deduplicator The link does not work for lambda with capture, right?

Comment: They work for any kind of object + member-function, be they a lambda or not. Of course, if your lambdas don't have captures, you could just convert to function-pointers. (BTW: Will try to add a better answer later. Need time for that.)

Comment: @Deduplicator You second link is really good, thank a lot.