# Why do I get a type deduction error for a lambda returning lambda with multiple return paths?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, return-type, return-type-deduction

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    auto f = [] {
        if (1) return [] { return 1; };
        else return [] { return 2; };
    };
    return f()();
}
```

which raises the following compiler error using GCC 5.2.1:

```
error: inconsistent types ‘main()::<lambda()>::<lambda()>’ and 
       ‘main()::<lambda()>::<lambda()>’ deduced for lambda 
       return type else return [] { return 2; };
```

Now obviously those two types look to be the same, so I'm not sure if this is GCC with a misleading error message or if it's actually a bug. According to my knowledge this should compile; the lambda return type should be deduced to be `std::function<int()>`. Interestingly, if I pre-declare the lambda return and return the same variable twice, it works.

Can anyone shed some light as to what is happening? I found similar looking questions, many attributed to GCC bugs, but this looks different.

Comment: they have different types: https://ideone.com/Eo4OXW

Comment: Thanks for editing my question to better format the code! I am unsure why I received a negative vote. I'd be happy to put in more "research effort" if needed. I felt this was a quite curious compiler error so I was hoping more knowledgeable people here would know what is going on. Please point me to any resources that I should use if this is nonconstructive.

Comment: I didn't really understand lambda types, sorry about that. The error message doesn't help, however...

Comment: I have no idea why you got a downvote. Well, other than my substantial experience with this particular community. :)

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit, this question is very useful to understand some substantial properties of lambda expressions.

Comment: @KerrekSB The types printed out by the compiler error message are the same and that is truth and there are obvious problems there. But I guess it's much less "interesting" if you know the answer. I didn't mean to flaunt around with any false information. In fact, I was envisioning the answer to be something of the sort posted below. Of course, all questions are answerable with enough homework. Anyway, thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477310/why-cant-i-create-a-vector-of-lambdas-of-the-same-type-in-c11#comment9050057_7477854 - i.e. a concise way to make your code work is to replace `return [] { ...` with `return *[] { ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Now obviously those two types are the same,

No, they're not. The type of every lambda expression is a unique, distinct type.

From [expr.prim.lambda]/3:

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the *closure type* — whose properties are described below.

Therefore, return type deduction for `f` *fails* and does not result in  `std::function<int()>`. The latter is an unrelated library type that isn't somehow magically the "common type" of any closure type.

Of course each of the unique closure types can be *converted* to `std::function<int()>`, so if you provide the return type, everything works:

```
auto f = []() -> std::function<int()> {
    return 1 ? []() { return 1; }
             : []() { return 2; };
};
```

Or, as a plain function:

```
std::function<int()> f() {
    return 1 ? []() { return 1; }
             : []() { return 2; };
}
```

Comment: I was referring to the strings in the compiler message, which are identical. I suppose why lambdas all have uniques types is an entirely different question. I've used lambdas for some time without knowing this and so thought this should compile. Thanks for pointing me to the standard.

Comment: @Alex: I agree, it's a terrible diagnostic message.

Comment: @Alex: I don't think "why lambdas have unique types" is a question at all. That's just how they're defined. I guess what would be a real question is "why do GCC diagnostics not show distinct types for different lambda expressions". That's well worth asking, perhaps on the GCC bug tracker.

Comment: @KerrekSB Surely someone had a reason for making them unique. It's very unsatisfying to answer such a question with "because it is so". Perhaps this points to a (giant) misunderstanding on my part, perhaps the answer requires months of reading, but it's still very much a real question.

Comment: @Alex: Perhaps. You could try and ask a question about design rationale, or you could look up the paper that proposed this language feature; surely it will contain that rationale.

Comment: FWIW, VC++ gives you the following message - not sure it's any better though. *error C3487: 'main::<lambda_ee7b0bdf7b482f76954b05f9e3de9c60>::()::<lambda_0c26d401ba5fe5b7cea369799397278b>': all return expressions must deduce to the same type: previously it was 'main::<lambda_ee7b0bdf7b482f76954b05f9e3de9c60>::()::<lambda_dd2a99334ae050357282bd65998e9f6d>'
1error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_ee7b0bdf7b482f76954b05f9e3de9c60>::()::<lambda_0c26d401ba5fe5b7cea369799397278b>' to 'main::<lambda_ee7b0bdf7b482f76954b05f9e3de9c60>::()::<lambda_dd2a99334ae050357282bd65998e9f6d>'*

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That looks a fair bit more useful, yes.

Comment: @Alex: Consider `auto f = []() mutable { static int n = 0; return ++n; }`. Do you want `n` to be shared among everyone who happens to type the same lambda?

Comment: @Alex: [Demo](https://ideone.com/tYSHCI). (The `mutable` is irrelevant, since `n` is a block-local variable, not a member.) Also, imagine that you would be asking to *deduce* a type based on an arbitrary token sequence. Would changing the names of local variables produce a different type or the same? There's just no end to the number of problems you'd face if you tried to specify some kind of type reuse for lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

Every lambda has its own, unique type:

> The lambda expression constructs an unnamed prvalue temporary object of **unique** unnamed non-union non-aggregate type[...].

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), emphasize mine.

Also, lambdas have nothing to do with `std::function`, that is another different type. In particular,

```
[] { return 1; }
```

and

```
[] { return 2; }
```

have different types. This is why deduction fails.

Answer (score 1):

Those types are *not* the same. Each lambda is an instance of a unique, unnamed type. `std::function` is a template that can be implicitely converted to from appropriate callable objects including lambdas, but no instantiation of `std::function` is type or parent type of any lambda so it cannot be deduced.

However, you can tell the compiler that you want it to return `std::function` and it will work:

```
auto f = []() -> std::function<int()> {
    if (1) return [] { return 1; };
    else return [] { return 2; };
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, `std::function` is a template, not a type. There isn't one single type that can be converted from *any* callable. For each function type there is a corresponding specialization of `std::function` that can be converted from callables of a compatible signature.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's more relaxed, you can have `std::function` with a different signature than the callable as long as the compiler can implicitely convert the types or fill in default parameters, and there is the weird handling of objects for member methods. The rules are pretty complex and I tried to avoid them completely.

Comment: Yes, that's why I tried to weasel around that by saying "compatible". But broadly speaking the specialization of `std::function` has to match what the callable is providing in some way; there is not a completely arbitrary catch-all type.